# how to access the member forms of a formset?

Tags: python, django, inline-formset, formset

I have an inline_formset for which I am using a custom form.  That form has various functions that I would like to call.  But, given an instance of the formset, how can I access that (those?) form(s)?

Here is some pseudo-code:

```
    class MyModel(models.Model):
        myField = models.ForeignKey(MyOtherModel)

    class MyOtherModel(models.Model):
        myField = models.CharField()

    class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = MyModel

    class MyOtherModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = MyOtherModel
        def foo(self):
          print "foo"

    MyFormSet = inlineformset_factory(MyModel,MyOtherModel,formset=MyOtherForm)

    def MyView(request):
        myModel = MyModel()
        myForm = MyModelForm(instance=myModel)
        myFormSet = MyFormSet(intance=myModel)

        # THIS FAILS...
        myFormSet.foo()
        # SO DOES THIS...
        myFormSet.forms[0].foo()
        # SO DOES THIS...
        myFormSet.form.foo()
        # ANY IDEAS?

        return render_to_response('my_view.html', {"form" : myForm, "formset" : myFormSet },context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Why do they fail? You need to throw you stack trace so ppl can see the actual error.

Comment: Please show code that properly demonstrates the issue. Here your factory call refers to a formset class that doesn't exist, and we don't even know if you are actually passing a form argument or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can access a formset's forms through `formset.forms`.

If `myFormSet.forms[0].foo()` fails then that probably means the formset does not have any forms. You haven't told us in what way it fails - `IndexError`?

If you are defining the `formset` in `inlineformset_factory`, have you made sure it inherits from `BaseModelFormSet`?